# Flash AS3 FlvPlayback Skin calling parent swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flvplayback

I have an FlvPlayback skin, which works really well, except the custom button. Basically this button needs to be able to call a function in the parent movieclip (that loaded the FlvPlayback, which in turn loaded the skin).

I am not really a Flash developer, and have not found anything on Google relating to this. It seems like a simple issue, but I just do not have enough knowledge of flash.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Summary: How to call a function in the base swf which has a FlvPlayback movieclip, from a custom button in the skin file.

Thanks

Comment: Sadly I cannot in this case, I understand it means this question is a lot harder to answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call just about any available method in the parent (or parent.parent) DisplayObject by using bracket syntax:

```
parent["name"]();
```

resp.

```
parent.parent["name"]();
```

where name is the name of your method.

If I remember correctly, your skin.swf's parent should be the FLVPlayback component, parent.parent the MovieClip containing it, and so forth. You can add a trace to the button's clickHandler to see which is correct.